# Notification Bar close button

Tags: html

Hi guys I have a website using opencart and I have a notification bar which tells users there is 10% off there first order however there is a close button but once you click close and refresh the page or visit it at a later time then it will show again, what I want is that when the user clicks close then it will not show again for 24 hours.
http://intoyoufashion.co.uk is my site which you can check it out to see what i mean.

Below is the code

```
<div id="Notify" style=" background-color:#DAA520; z-index:999;font-size:16px; text-align:center; color:#fff; position:fixed;width:100%;height:18px;top:0px;">Use code open10 at checkout for 10% off your first order<button class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('Notify').style.display='none'" >Close</button></div>
```

Thanks, if you guys can be of help.

Comment: You shall use cookies to turn off the notification.

Comment: Thanks mate how do i use cookies and what would the code be that i need.

Answer (score 0):

please add the following code blocks to your  common.js

```
//First code block ---start
$('#Notify button').click(function(){
  $('#Notify').css("display", "none");
  localStorage.setItem("offer_exp", new Date().getTime() + (60 * 60 * 24));
});
// ----End of first code block
$(document).ready(function() {
 //second code block --start 
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("offer_exp")) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("offer_exp") <= new Date().getTime()) {
        $('#Notify').css("display", "block");
    }
    else{
      $('#Notify').css("display", "none");
    }
} else {
    $('#Notify').css("display", "block");
}
//-----end of second code block
    /* Search */
    $('.button-search').bind('click', function() {
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

        if (search) {
            url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
        }

        location = url;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks sajan, do i keep my previous code where it is or remove it thanks.

Comment: No it wont affect your old codes, you need to 

 just and that 2 code block to your current code 

i commented end and start position of code blocks, copy that and paste in correct position